# namespace classes, functions and how to use

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

Decided to start using namespaces in my PHP projects and am struggling in getting this simple setup to work... What am I doing wrong?

**First.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace;
use PDO;

class First {
    function hello() {
        return 'hello';
    }
}
```

**Second.php**

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace;
use PDO;
use function \MyNamespace\First;

class Second {
    function world() {
        $firstpart = \MyNamespace\First::hello();
        return $firstpart . ' world';
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
echo \MyNamespace\Second::world();
?>
```

This gives me an error:

**Strict Standards:** Non-static method MyNamespace\Second::world() should not be called statically in /var/www/testsite/index.php on line 2

Basically, I am looking for a way to call different functions in different classes within the same namespace. Have never used namespaces before and for the life of me however I try to call my functions, they end up giving me the same errors. Any pointers please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error indicates an attempt to call a static method, which is not (class **Second**, method **world** - not static)

And importing function space names must be as follows:

**First.php**

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace;
function hello() {
        return 'hello';
 }
```

**Second.php**

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace;
use function \MyNamespace\First\hello;

class Second {
    static function world() {
        $firstpart = hello();
        return $firstpart . ' world';
    }
}
```

And use, for example:

```
 Second::world()
```

(I add **static** word in declaration method world)

[Read this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)